# OnMeasure и Андроид 9

Tags: android, android-sdk

Есть текствью с шириной MathParent, в него программно вставляется некоторый текст. Если текст не влез (перенос строки или "..."), то текст должен быть программно изменен. Я сделал это через кастомную TextView, в которой перекрыл onMeasure. В OnMeasure я проверяю lineCount (количество строк) текствьюшки и, если он >1, нужным образом меняю текст в ней. И, казалось бы, всё работает, НО! На 9ом андроиде оно работать наполовину перестает. Если точнее, при создании активити onMeasure исправно вызывается, но lineCount в нём всегда 0. Причем при следующем проходе onMeasure всё отлично обрабатывается. Я попробовал вызвать customTextView.measure() руками в конце onResume активити, но ситуация не меняется. Хотя, если сделать кнопку, которая будет вызывать customTextView.measure() при нажатии пользователем, - всё корректно обрабатывается. Подскажите плиз, где нужно вызвать measure, чтобы он корректно обработался? И я не совсем понимаю, почему на API 28 это перестало происходить автоматически... Или, возможно, есть более грамотное решение данного кейса без обработки onMeasure?

Comment: может сделать так https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616631/textview-cuts-off-text-when-it-is-long-enough

Comment: Надо не обрезать текствью и не прокрутить, а определенным образом изменить содержимое текствьюхи.

Comment: для "определенных образов" пишут свои. перегружая оригинал

Comment: Он и так перегружен. Если прочитать вопрос, это становится понятно.

Comment: имеется ввиду отрисовка

Comment: Именно это я и спрашивал: что именно нужно перегрузить и как при проверить, влез ли текст в доступное пространство. А Вы мне советуете "перегрузить оригинал", очень конструктивно.

Comment: ну на этом сайте не принято хамить, хотя я мог бы помочь, удачи

Comment: Вы сначала ссылкой ответили мимо вопроса, даже не прочитав его, потом дважды написали какие-то абсолютно неинформативные советы в стиле "Как сделать ...? - Написать код, который это делает" , а теперь удивляетесь, что Вам кто-то якобы "хамит". На самом же деле Вам аргументированно объясняют, что вместо помощи вы льете воду и по существу ничего до сих пор не сказали. Видимо, так "на этом сайте принято"? Такой "помощи" мне не нужно, спасибо. Вам тоже удачи и всего наилучшего.

Comment: вы научитесь кратко и правильно формулировать вопросы, и потом вам будут помогать остальные участники, а не только я. Вам же проще обвинить кого-то только не себя. К вашему сведению в комментариях дают ссылки и наводки, а вам уже самому решать принимать к сведению или игнорировать, но не хамить. А ответы дают ниже.